# Android/Java: How to set pivotType for view.setScale in java?

Tags: android, animation

I want to program `scale` a view in java code and I don't know how to set `pivotType` for `scale`.
I'm using below code:

```
ImageView ivHorizontal = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.splash_forth_iv_horizontal);
    ivHorizontal.setPivotX(0);
    ivHorizontal.setPivotY(1);
    ivHorizontal.setScaleX(1.3f);
    ivHorizontal.setScaleY(1.3f);
```

I also read some topics related to this problem and tried to use :

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(1f, 1.3f, 1f, 1.3f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1);
    scaleAnimation.setDuration(0);
    scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    ivHorizontal.startAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

but it's not work enough for me.

I want to find something as

```
    ivHorizontal.setPivotXType(Animation.RElATED_TO_SEFT);
    ivHorizontal.setPivotYType(Animation.RElATED_TO_SEFT);
    ivHorizontal.setPivotX(0);
    ivHorizontal.setPivotY(1);
    ivHorizontal.setScaleX(1.3f);
    ivHorizontal.setScaleY(1.3f);
```

Is there any idea to help ???

Comment: there is no such method: `setPivotXType`

Comment: I know that there is no method but I want to ask is there any way to do it

Comment: just use `setPivotX` / `setPivotY`, whats unclear in those methods?

Comment: I want to set pivot type for setScaleX and setScaleY as Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF but default value is another value

Comment: see: `mPivotX = resolveSize(mPivotXType, mPivotXValue, width, parentWidth);  mPivotY = resolveSize(mPivotYType, mPivotYValue, height, parentHeight);`, http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.java#286

Comment: that method is protected and can not be called

Comment: this shows how pivot x / y values are computed, just see what is done in case of RELATIVE_TO_SELF

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but I mean I want to set pivotType and the above code is just about the value of pivot and pivotType always is ABSOLUTE

Comment: you cannot set pivot type, there is no such method like `setPivotXType`, all you need is to call `setPivotX` with valid x pivot value, the location is in pixels, starting with left-top corner